# Capture raw content POST'ed to MVC 3 Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC 3 Application which has JSON POST'ed to an Action. Everything works fine, but I need to start logging the raw inbound JSON blobs (*or whatever else is being sent*). Specifically, I want to capture requests that fail before hitting the target Action so I can analyze structural and/or content issues with the data being POST'ed.

Is something like this possible in MVC 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to analyze eveything, that comes to server, consider using HTTP module: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx.

HTTP Module is a class, that allows you to attach additional actions to existing request flow. You can attach your code to BeginRequest event to log request details, even if it won't reach controller.

```
public class HelloWorldModule : IHttpModule {
    // In the Init function, register for HttpApplication 
    // events by adding your handlers.
    public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        application.BeginRequest += 
            (new EventHandler(this.Application_BeginRequest));
    }

    private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, 
         EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do something with HttpContext.Current.Request here
    } 
}
```

Comment: This would have been my approach for a non-MVC ASP.NET Application. I was assuming there may be an MVC specific mechanism to accessing the RAW POST'd content. I will give this a try.

Comment: @JoeGeeky: MVC shares a lot of mechanisms with WebForms and HTTP handlers is one of them. It is completely normal to use them in MVC applications. As Muhammad Adeel Zahid, ELMAH can be useful here too.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do it yourself. There are some open source solutions that do the job quite well. Most famous is probably [log4net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14819/How-to-use-log4net) and next down the list is [elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) which is basically an HTTP module